# openGL/Pyglet texture graphics vanish when drawing sprites

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

My code draws a 3D world, with a 2D set of graphics on top of it. The 3D world is made out of textured quads and the textures are generated  with the following code:

```
textures = []

image = pyglet.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, "magic.png"))

textures.append(image.get_texture())

glEnable(textures[-1].target)
glBindTexture(textures[-1].target, textures[-1].id)
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, image.width, image.height,
    0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    image.get_image_data().get_data('RGBA',
    image.width * 4))
```

The quads are then drawn with (the other 2 just have different coords):

```
glBindTexture(texture.target, texture.id)
glBegin(GL_QUADS)
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(4.0, -2.0, 100.0+self.clock)
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(4.0, -2.0, -100.0+self.clock)
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(-4.0,  -2.0, -100.0+self.clock)
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(-4.0,  -2.0, 100.0+self.clock)
glEnd()
```

I have set up the correct parameters when drawing the 3D and 2D graphics, and when I draw a 2D triangle on top of the 3D quad (with the following code) everything works fine:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
glVertex3f(0.0, 10, 0.0)
glVertex3f(-10, -10, 0)
glVertex3f(10, -10, 0)
glEnd()
```

[image: Working Textures]

However, I then try to draw a sprite and the 3D quads lose their texture and are drawn as white.

```
self.spr=pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, "largebullet.png")).get_texture())
...
self.spr.draw()
```

[image: Broken textures]
Note that there's some fog in the background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this, by running glDisable(texture.target) on the enabled textures after they were drawn. It's not ideal because they have to be reenabled again, but for now it works ok.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem to this, and I found that the pyglet `Sprite` class tends to disable everything in the OpenGL state that it sets. You must reset a lot of things each time any sprite is drawn.

Comment: That's the problem with Pyglet and other high level graphics libraries - they're so far away from OpenGL itself that you have no idea what's going on under the bonnet. I've now gone onto using C++ and OpenGL directly for a different project of mine and not only is everything clearer, but it also feels more rewarding.